# jquery about attributes ( load from loaded html )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2 select options. When I select the first one it posts to a link using javascript then return full options to the second one with data from a database.

I have an attributes in the second select called `data-price`. When I'm trying to use it, it shows nothing:

```
var x = $("#services").find(':selected').attr('data-price');
```

However when I'm trying with the first select attribute it works correctly. Anyone know how to fix ? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var category = document.getElementById("category").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=base_url();?>dashboard/ajaxData',
        data:'main_category='+category,
        success:function(html){
        $('#services').html(html);
        }
    }); 
    $('#category').on('change',function(){
        var category = $(this).val();
        if(category){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?=base_url();?>dashboard/ajaxData',
                data:'main_category='+category,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#services').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#services').html('<option value="">Select category first</option>');
        }
    });

});
    var x = $("#services").find(':selected').attr('data-price');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

</script>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>

            <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach($categories->result() as $cat): ?>
                <option data-price="55" value="<?=$cat->id;?>">- <?=$cat->title;?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Service</label>

            <select name="service" id="services" class="form-control">
            <option data-price=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>  
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: you can use  .data() method too

$("#services").find(':selected').data('price'); To get a proper answer put your html too

Comment: without HTML no luck to get help

Comment: First simplify the problem. Be sure, is problem finding element or getting attribute.  console.log the x object or x.html().

Comment: I added the code to show u, thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the data attributes correctly? You didn't share the HTML returned by your AJAX call.

Comment: <select name="service" id="services" class="form-control"><option data-price="5" value="1">- Testing service bla  bla  bla  bla  bla </option></select> , this is the return

Comment: Is this your actual code and layout of your file? If so, the code in question is outside the jQuery ready function, therefore runs before the document is rendered, before the DOM is ready. Even if you run it within the ready function, you don't have any price data attributes set before the AJAX call returns.

Comment: I thought that too , I moved it before and inner and after but same.

Comment: Oh , I fixed it , thanks very much it was about putting it after $('#services').html(html); , Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the selected one you do:

```
$("#services option:selected")
```

then you can get whatever you want from that option. 
For a data attribute it can be:

```
$("#services option:selected").data('price');
```

or alternatively

```
$("#services option:selected").attr('data-price');
```

This answer is based on the assumption that your select as an id attribute of services, if it is not all the above code will fail

Based on the updated code you posted you probably are looking to update the selected value when the user changes the selection.
I'd do it binding the change event like this:

```
$("#services option:selected").change(function(){
    var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
    $('#demo').html(price);
});
```

Comment: Thank you , the problem was about the place of services option:selected , it should be after $('#services').html(html); , Thank you again.